# Intersection of integer sequences

Tags: list-manipulation

I've been stuck on this question for a solid hour.

> Create two lists of all integers which can be written as (i) $i^2−j^2$ or (ii) $i^3 − j^3$ for $1 ≤ i, j ≤ 100$ . Find the largest number in the intersection of these two sets.

I kept on trying it with two lists before eventually figuring out I should use a `Table` and now I've arrived at

```
firsttwelve = Table[i^2 - j^2, {i, 100}, {j, 100}];
secondtwelve = Table[i^3 - j^3, {i, 100}, {j, 100}];
Intersection[firsttwelve, secondtwelve]
```

but the intersection keeps on coming up as empty. Is there a different function I should use or am I making some other error?

Comment: Hint: `Intersection[Flatten[firsttwelve], Flatten[secondtwelve]]`

Comment: Just to elaborate on @Bill's hint, `Dimensions /@ {firsttwelve, secondtwelve}` shows you that your trying to find the intersection between two 100 by 100 matrices, which will only be non-empty if the two matrices have one or more _rows_ (each consisting of 100 numbers) in common. Clearly this isn't going to happen. `Flatten`ing makes them both lists of 10,000 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the lists of differences with a single call to `Table`.

```
{squareDif, cubeDif} = 
   Transpose @ Catenate @ Table[{i^2 - j^2, i^3 - j^3}, {i, 100}, {j, 100}];
```

Then

```
Max @@ Intersection[squareDif, cubeDif]
```

gives

> `9919`